# How to pass byte[] array from InputStrem to OutputStream?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inputstream, outputstream

I have stored my `image as mediumblob` in database

In my Image bean class I have store photo property as byte[] like

```
private byte[] photo;

// getter and setter method for photo
```

I get image from database using to store in Image bean class

```
image.setPhoto(resultset.getBinaryStreams(1));
```

then i get the image in Servlet as:

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
try {
    input = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getPhoto());

    output = // What type of stream should I use here

    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    output.flush();
    input.close();
}
```

Questions:

1. WHat should I write at output line to show photo using response.getOutputStream or something else?
2. Is this method correct or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `output` stream can be that stream returned by `response.getOutputStream()` directly. Just be sure to flush the stream after writing all the data to it.

If your servlet container isn't buffering output streams, you can consider wrapping the output in a `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: Not only does the servlet container buffer, it writes to a ByteArrayOutputStream, so it can compute the Content-Length header. You don't have to buffer yourself.

Comment: I have done this `ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();` and getting `NPE Exception at output.flush();`

Comment: Are you able to write to it before the call to flush()?

Comment: Well, if I had to guess, I'd say that the line `input = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getPhoto());` is failing. Either because `image` is `null` or `image.getPhoto()` returns `null`. Your `finally` block should be check both `input` and `output` for `null` since they are `null` outside the `try/finally` block.